# Sql Subquery not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

this is my subquery but it's doesn't work :

```
SELECT     CommitmentLog.app_id, CommitmentLog.CommitAmt, CommitmentLog.CommitDate, 
    CommitmentLog.status, CommitmentLog.ConfirmDate, Appreg.uid, Appreg.SpillBy,  
    Appreg.spill, Appreg.Email, Appreg.pass, Appreg.intro_id, Appreg.app_id AS Expr1
FROM  CommitmentLog 
INNER JOIN  Appreg ON CommitmentLog.app_id = Appreg.app_id 
where Appreg.app_id = 
(
    SELECT dbo.UIDFromApp_ID(Intro_id) as 'SponsorUserID', [app_id],[uid], [app_name], [Side], [doj] 
    FROM [v_Appreg] 
    WHERE ([Intro_id] = 1496)
)
```

it gives error :

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Comment: Is it sql-server or mysql?

Comment: subquery does not work for mutiple fields... try with single field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using MSSQL (the error looks SQL-Serverish) and you're looking for `app_id` in your subquery, something like this should be what you're after.

```
SELECT 
    CommitmentLog.app_id, 
    CommitmentLog.CommitAmt, 
    CommitmentLog.CommitDate, 
    CommitmentLog.status, 
    CommitmentLog.ConfirmDate, 
    Appreg.uid, 
    Appreg.SpillBy, 
    Appreg.spill, 
    Appreg.Email, 
    Appreg.pass, 
    Appreg.intro_id, 
    Appreg.app_id AS Expr1

FROM CommitmentLog 
INNER JOIN Appreg 
    ON CommitmentLog.app_id = Appreg.app_id 
WHERE Appreg.app_id IN 
    (SELECT [app_id] FROM [v_Appreg] WHERE ([Intro_id] = 1496))
```

Exactly as the error said, you can only have a single value in a subquery when trying to use an `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you it is necessary to only retrieve one value in your subquery.

```
SELECT
    CommitmentLog.app_id,
    CommitmentLog.CommitAmt,
    CommitmentLog.CommitDate, 
    CommitmentLog.status,
    CommitmentLog.ConfirmDate,
    Appreg.uid,
    Appreg.SpillBy,  
    Appreg.spill,
    Appreg.Email,
    Appreg.pass,
    Appreg.intro_id,
    Appreg.app_id AS Expr1

FROM
    CommitmentLog INNER JOIN  Appreg ON CommitmentLog.app_id = Appreg.app_id

WHERE
    Appreg.app_id = 
        (SELECT dbo.UIDFromApp_ID(Intro_id) as 'SponsorUserID' FROM [v_Appreg] WHERE [Intro_id] = 1496)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong.  You are trying to say

```
where appreg.app_id = 
(select dbo.UIDFromApp_ID(Intro_id) as 'SponsorUserID', [app_id], etc
```

That's ambiguous.  You have to assign only one value to the field.

Once you sort that out, you are subject to another problem.  If your subquery returns more than one row, it's once again ambiguous.  You'll have to do something about that.  The details depend on your requirements.